# Permission denied while trying to call alarm clock

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alarms

I was trying to write an app which needs the user to set an alarm. I tried to call the alarm clock with the intent using following code

```
    Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "MMTS train to catch rush up ...");
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, d.getHours());
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, d.getMinutes());
    activity.startActivity(i);
```

exception is

```
    Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SET_ALARM
    cmp=com.android.deskclock/.HandleSetAlarm (has extras) } from
    ProcessRecord{414d1210 812:com.arjun.android.mmts/10041} (pid=812, uid=10041)
    requires com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM
```

I am working on Android 4.0 API version 14.

I added the line

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"></uses-permission>
```

in my manifest file, even after that it was not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to declare the offending permission in your manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="you.package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    .
    .
    .
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
    .
    .
    .
</manifest>
```

Comment: i added that even after that it was not working sorry for not adding this in the question, i will add it now.

Comment: Please look again at my answer. The permission that you have shown in your question is *different* to the one that I'm suggesting you use.

Comment: sorry mark i just over looked it, it worked as a charm can you please tell me why it started working whats the difference between two things?

Comment: If you are using a system permission, then the permission that you declare must exactly match that defined by Android. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#permissions for more information.